# Use android A-GPS in my application

Tags: java, android, gps

I want to use A-GPS in my app. Do I have to implement some functionalities by myself or, when WiFi / Data network and GPS is On, Android automatically uses A-GPS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AGPS is all done behind the scenes. There is no Android device that I know of that uses pure GPS. They all use a combination of GPS and cell tower/network location.

You don't need to do anything on your side. The framework will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) is is a great source of android tutorials, link is direct to one regarding gps or location services

Comment: While it's a good tutorial about GPS, it doesn't even mention A-GPS, so not a relevant answer to this question.